# nextjs <a> inside <Link> results in 2 history stacks

Tags: next.js, anchor

When I click on `Hello`, it redirects ok but to browse back to where i was by clicking back button, it requires 2 back button clicks. (probably because `<Link>` and `<a>` are triggered at the same time)

```js
export default function Navigation() {
  const router = useRouter()
  
  const menus = [
    { key: 'key1', title: 'title1', clasName: 'class1' },
    { key: 'key2', title: 'title2', clasName: 'class2' },
  ]

  return (
    <div role="tablist">
      {menus.map(({ key, title, className }) => (
        <Link
          href={{
            pathname: router.pathname,
            query: {
              menu: key
            }
          }}>
          <a
            className={className}
            role="tab">
            <span>{title}</span>
          </a>
        </Link>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}
```

I have to use `<a>` to apply `className`.
Only using `<a>` causes page to rerender even when `href` is same as current page.

What should I do to prevent 2 history stacks being inserted?

Thanks!

Comment: That's not because of next/link and anchor tag. Anchor tag is meant to be nested inside `Link`. There is some other problem with your code.

Comment: Share the full code of component you are using

Comment: @illiachill I added a little bit simplifed version of the full code

Comment: @brc-dd I added the full code. Do you see anything that can be a problem?

Comment: I have tested your code, no issues were detected. Inserting only 1 history per click. Every time you click your `key` it records as a history. It is the default behavior of browser/navigation. If you like some more advanced case, you need to implement `filtering` based on your code and not linking strategy.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it was my custom `popstate` event listener that was pushing an extra stack into `History`. Thanks all for your comments